# changing the the last part of binaries or text by other binaries and text or Least significant bit method

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have 8 binary example:

0100010**0**, 1001000**1**,1001000**0**,1001000**1**,1001000**1**,1001000**0**,1001000**1**,1001000**0**

I want to change the bold bits with a text that converted to binary and input the binary into the last part of the 8 binaries

For example:

`h = 01101000`.

Acually I'm trying to use least significant bit but I don't know how to code it.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim img As New Bitmap(TextBox1.Text)

    For w As Integer = 0 To img.Width - 1
        For h As Integer = 0 To img.Height - 1
            Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(w, h)


            Dim pix As Integer = pixel.R
            Dim pix2bin As String = Convert.ToString(pix, 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
            Console.WriteLine(pix2bin)


            ' Dim txtasc As Integer = Asc(TextBox2.Text)
            'Dim txtbin As String = Convert.ToString(txtasc, 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
            'Console.WriteLine(txtbin)



            ' img.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(lsb method, pixel.G, pixel.B))

        Next
    Next
    Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFile.Filter = "Image Files (*.png, *.bmp, ) |*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg"
    saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\Desktop"

    If saveFile.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = saveFile.FileName.ToString()
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = TextBox1.Text
        img.Save(TextBox1.Text)

    End If
    Return
End Sub
```

Comment: First, pick a language. Second, tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: im using vb.net. actually im trying to make steganography program using lsb this is my code so far.

Comment: theres my code sir thank you i dont know what im doing really. im kinda new in visual basic

Comment: i dont know how im gonna add the text bits to the pixel binary

Comment: Okay, this is a good example of asking for the solution to the wrong problem. There is no reason to convert your byte to a string in order to edit it. Changing the least significant bit in a byte is just XOR'ing by 1.

Comment: do you have a sample code of XOR code? ive search and i dont know how to code sorry im really a new in visual basic

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Sir this XOR is killing me. i dont how it works on my steganography

Comment: Is the commented out code with the text box important? If so, how is it used?

Comment: yep the textbox is important. example im gonna input "hello" to textbox and it will convert to binary. i want each of the bits of binary in the text will be inputted each last bit of the pixels that has been converted to binary. im really sorry for the bad english

Comment: and i have another problem i want is 1 xor 1 will be equal 1

Comment: Then I misunderstood your requirements. You want `And`, not `Xor`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so now that I understand your question, you need two things.

First, you need a function that will convert a string into a byte array. This takes some bit-wise operations, but it's fairly straightforward:

```
Public Shared Function StringToBinary(str As String) As Byte()
    Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)()
    Dim buf As Byte() = Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(str)

    For i As Integer = 0 To buf.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To (8) - 1
            bytes.Insert(8 * i, CByte((buf(i) >> j) And 1))
        Next
    Next

    Return bytes.ToArray()
End Function
```

Then you need to call this function just once before your pixel loop. In the loop, you use `And` to embed a binary digit into the least significant digit of a color's red channel:

```
Dim bin As Byte() = StringToBinary(TextBox1.Text)
Dim idx = 0

For w As Integer = 0 To img.Width - 1
    If idx >= bin.Length Then
        Return
    End If

    For h As Integer = 0 To img.Height - 1
        If idx >= bin.Length Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(w, h)
        Dim red = pixel.R
        red = red And bin(idx)

        img.SetPixel(w, h, Color.FromArgb(red, pixel.G, pixel.B))

        idx += 1
    Next
Next
```

*(I'm a C# programmer and don't know VB very well. I wrote this code in C# and converted it with the [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/). With that in mind, the code could probably be optimized further.)*

As a side note, the `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` functions are notoriously slow, and are not the recommended way to edit a `Bitmap`'s pixels. For a more recommended way, look into how to use [`Bitmap.LockPixels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).